# Simplify symbolic expressions

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am new in Lisp and i need some help.
I need to simplify next expressions:
from `(+ (+ A B) C)` to `(+ A B C)`
and from `(- (- A B) C)` to `(- A B C)`.

If you could help me with one of them I'll understand how i need to do this to the next one.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an input that matches this pattern, `(+ e1 ... en)`, you want to recursively simplify all `e1` to `en`, which gives you `s1`, ..., `sn`, and then extract all the `si` that start with a `+` to move their arguments one level up, to the simplified expression you are building.

- An expression `e` matches the above pattern if `(and (consp e) (eq '+ (car e)))`.
- Then, all the `ei` are just given by the list that is `(cdr e)`.
- Consider the `(+)` case, how could you simplify it?
- To apply a function `f` to a list of values, call `(mapcar #'f list)`.
- To split a list into two lists, based on a predicate `p`, you might use a loop:

  ```
  (let ((sat nil) (unsat nil))
    (dolist (x list (values sat unsat))
      (if (funcall predicate x) 
          (push x sat) 
          (push x unsat))))
  ```

  There is a purely functional way to write this, can you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trivial simplifier written in Racket, with an implementation of a rather mindless simplifier for `+`.  Note that this is not intended as anything serious: it's just what I typed in when I was thinking about this question.

This uses Racket's pattern matching, probably in a naïve way, to do some of the work.

```
(define/match (simplify expression)
  ;; simplifier driver
  (((cons op args))
   ;; An operator with some arguments
   ;; Note that this assumes that the arguments to operators are always
   ;; expressions to simplify, so the recursive level can be here
   (simplify-op op (map simplify args)))
  ((expr)
   ;; anything else
   expr))

(define op-table (make-hash))

(define-syntax-rule (define-op-simplifier (op args) form ...)
  ;; Define a simplifier for op with arguments args
  (hash-set! op-table 'op (λ (args) form ...)))

(define (simplify-op op args)
  ;; Note the slightly arcane fallback: you need to wrap it in a thunk
  ;; so hash-ref does not try to call it.
  ((hash-ref op-table op (thunk (λ (args) (cons op args)))) args))

(define-op-simplifier (+ exprs)
  ;; Simplify (+ ...) by flattening + in its arguments
  (let loop ([ftail exprs]
             [results '()])
    (if (null? ftail)
        `(+ ,@(reverse results))
        (loop (rest ftail)
              (match (first ftail)
                [(cons '+ addends)
                 (append (reverse addends) results)]
                [expr (cons expr results)])))))
```

It is possible to be more aggressive than this.  For instance we can coalesce runs of literal numbers, so we can simplify `(+ 1 2 3 a 4)` to
`(+ 6 a 4)` (note it is not safe in general to further simplify this to `(+ 10 a)` unless all arithmetic is exact).  Here is a function which does this coalescing for for `+` and `*`:

```
(define (coalesce-literal-numbers f elts)
  ;; coalesce runs of literal numbers for an operator f.
  ;; This relies on the fact that (f) returns a good identity for f
  ;; (so in particular it returns an exact number).  Thisis true for Racket
  ;; and CL and I think any Lisp worth its salt.
  ;;
  ;; Note that it's important here that (eqv? 1 1.0) is false.
  ;;;
  (define id (f))
  (let loop ([tail elts]
             [accum id]
             [results '()])
    (cond [(null? tail)
           (if (not (eqv? accum id))
               (reverse (cons accum results))
               (reverse results))]
          [(number? (first tail))
           (loop (rest tail)
                 (f accum (first tail))
                 results)]
          [(eqv? accum id)
           (loop (rest tail)
                 accum
                 (cons (first tail) results))]
          [else
           (loop (rest tail)
                 id
                 (list* (first tail) accum results))])))
```

And here is a modified simplifier for `+` which uses this.  As well as coalescing it notices that `(+ x)` can be simplified to `x`.

```
(define-op-simplifier (+ exprs)
  ;; Simplify (+ ...) by flattening + in its arguments
  (let loop ([ftail exprs]
             [results '()])
    (if (null? ftail)
        (let ([coalesced (coalesce-literal-numbers + (reverse results))])
          (match coalesced
            [(list something)
             something]
            [exprs
             `(+ ,@exprs)]))
        (loop (rest ftail)
              (match (first ftail)
                [(cons '+ addends)
                 (append (reverse addends) results)]
                [expr (cons expr results)])))))
```

Here is an example of using this enhanced simplifier:

```
> (simplify 'a)
'a
> (simplify 1)
1
> (simplify '(+ 1 a))
'(+ 1 a)
> (simplify '(+ a (+ b c)))
'(+ a b c)
> (simplify '(+ 1 (+ 3 c) 4))
'(+ 4 c 4)
> (simplify '(+ 1 2 3))
6
```

For yet more value you can notice that the simplifier for `*` is really the same, and change things to this:

```
(define (simplify-arith-op op fn exprs)
  (let loop ([ftail exprs]
             [results '()])
    (if (null? ftail)
        (let ([coalesced (coalesce-literal-numbers fn (reverse results))])
          (match coalesced
            [(list something)
             something]
            ['()
             (fn)]
            [exprs
             `(,op ,@exprs)]))
        (loop (rest ftail)
              (match (first ftail)
                [(cons the-op addends)
                 #:when (eqv? the-op op)
                 (append (reverse addends) results)]
                [expr (cons expr results)])))))

(define-op-simplifier (+ exprs)
  (simplify-arith-op '+ + exprs))

(define-op-simplifier (* exprs)
  (simplify-arith-op '* * exprs))
```

And now

```
(simplify '(+ a (* 1 2 (+ 4 5)) (* 3 4) 6 (* b)))
'(+ a 36 b)
```

Which is reasonably neat.

You can go further than this,  For instance when coalescing numbers for an operator you can simply elide sequences of the identity for that operator: `(* 1 1 a 1 1 b)` can be simplified to `(* a b)`, not `(* 1 a 1 b)`.  It may seem silly to do that: who would ever write such an expression, but they can quite easily occur when simplifying complicated expressions.

There is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/tfeb/fbad1827e375da704a71799793f1e332) of an elaborated version of this code.  It may still be buggy.